# Images file in folder is sorted in alphabetical order. However appended list is not in that order

Tags: python

Appended list is not in the correct order as shown in the file directory.

```
directory = Path('file directory')
images = []
for entry in directory.iterdir():
    images.append(entry.name) 
print()
```

Comment: Which order do you want to keep image's names?

Comment: Hi noobprogrammerkk, what order are you expecting and what order is in your file directory?

Comment: I have a number of images that is sorted in alphabetical order in my folder

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46332012/python-sorted-file-list) question out, there are already solutions for this issue.

Comment: Paths are ordered by lexicographical order of their corresponding components. Paths are not strings, and this this order is more natural for them. from https://bugs.python.org/msg306306

Answer (score 1):

If you want your `images` list in alphabetical order, then you can do after loop:

```
images = sorted(images, key=str.swapcase)
```